# What is the python equivalent of JavaScript's Array.prototype.some / every?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Does python have any equivalent to JavaScript's [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) / [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)?

Trivial JavaScript example:

```
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
arr.some(function (element, index) {
    console.log("index: " + index + ", element: " + element)
    if(element === "b"){
        return true;
    }
});
```

Will output:

```
index: 0, element: a
index: 1, element: b
```

The below python seems to be functionally equivalent, but I do not know if there is a more "pythonic" approach.

```
arr = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
for index, element in enumerate(arr):
    print("index: %i, element: %s" % (index, element))
    if element == "b":
        break
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Python has `all(iterable)` and `any(iterable)`. So if you make a generator or an iterator that does what you want, you can test it with those functions. For example:

```
some_is_b = any(x == 'b' for x in ary)
all_are_b = all(x == 'b' for x in ary)
```

They are actually defined in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) by their code equivalents. Does this look familiar?

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Of course the python names are better, shorter and more logical. "some" just isnt quite right.

Answer (score 2):

No. [NumPy arrays have](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), but standard python lists don't. Even so, the numpy array implementations are not what you'd expect: they don't take a predicate, but evaluate every element by converting them to boolean.

**Edit**: `any` and `all` exist as functions (not as methods), but they don't apply predicates, but consider booleanized values as numpy methods.

In Python, `some` could be:

```
def some(list_, pred):
    return bool([i for i in list_ if pred(i)])

#or a more efficient approach, which doesn't build a new list
def some(list_, pred):
    return any(pred(i) for i in list_) #booleanize the values, and pass them to any
```

You could implement `every`:

```
def every(list_, pred):
    return all(pred(i) for i in list_)
```

**Edit**: dumb sample:

```
every(['a', 'b', 'c'], lambda e: e == 'b')
some(['a', 'b', 'c'], lambda e: e == 'b')
```

Try them by urself

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
def callback( n ):
    return (n % 2 == 0)

# 1) Demonstrates how list() works with an iterable
isEvenList = list( callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(isEvenList)

# 2) Demonstrates how any() works with an iterable
anyEvenNumbers = any( callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(anyEvenNumbers)

# 3) Demonstrates how all() works with an iterable
allEvenNumbers = all( callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(allEvenNumbers)
```

1. list() takes any iterable, returns another list:

```
isEvenList = list(callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(isEvenList)
#[False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

2. any(): needs just one True in a list of booleans, returns a boolean:

```
anyEvenNumbers = any( callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(anyEvenNumbers)
#True
```

3. all(): needs all True values in a list of booleans, returns a boolean:

```
allEvenNumbers = all( callback(n) for n in numbers)
print(allEvenNumbers)
#False
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.