# Equivalent of JavaScript's Array.some() in Python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Is there an equivalent to array's `some()` method in Python?

If you're not familiar with this method, this is what it does:

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

The provided function is obviously a predicate (boolean function).
Here is a simple example:

```js
const numbers = [1, 3, 7, 22];
const isEven = number => number % 2 === 0;

const atLeastOneEven = numbers.some(isEven);
// true
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25488148/8804293)

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much